# How (rather, why?) do I assign weights to outcomes in an experiment (described below)?

Tags: probability

The experiment involves the following steps:

1. Choose at random 1 die from a bag containing 5 dice (1 each of 4 sided, 6 sided 8 sided 12 sided and 20 sided die)
2. Roll chosen die once
3. Observe the outcome.

Using Baye's conditional probability,

[Notation: let P($A$) denote the probability of occurrence of outcome $A$; where 1≤$A$≤20, $A$⊆$N$ (the set of natural numbers)]

P(1) = P(1|4 sided die chosen) + P(1|6 sided die chosen) + P(1|8 sided die chosen) + P(1|12 sided die chosen) + P(1|20 sided die chosen) = $\frac{1}{4}$+$\frac{1}{6}$+$\frac{1}{8}$+$\frac{1}{12}$+$\frac{1}{20}$ = 0.675.

I cannot understand how the weight (probability of choosing a die from the bag containing five dice) $\frac{1}{5}$ comes into play here; unless the premise is flawed. In which case, how?

Comment: What do you mean?  The first term on the right, for example, is $\frac 15 \times \text {(the probability of picking d(4) and getting a 1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation but also $\def\die{{\small\mathrm d}}\die4, \die6, \die 8, \die 12, \die 20$ to denote the events of using the relevant dice, then the Law of Total Probability will give you:

$\begin{split}\mathsf P(1)&=\mathsf P(1\mid\die 4)\mathsf P(\die 4)+\mathsf P(1\mid\die 6)\mathsf P(\die 6)+\mathsf P(1\mid\die 8)\mathsf P(\die 8)+\mathsf P(1\mid\die 12)\mathsf P(\die 12)+\mathsf P(1\mid\die 20)\mathsf P(\die 20)\\ &= \tfrac 14\tfrac 15+\tfrac 16\tfrac 15+\tfrac 18\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{12}\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{20}\tfrac 15\\ \mathsf P(2)&= \tfrac 14\tfrac 15+\tfrac 16\tfrac 15+\tfrac 18\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{12}\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{20}\tfrac 15\\\mathsf P(3)&= \tfrac 14\tfrac 15+\tfrac 16\tfrac 15+\tfrac 18\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{12}\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{20}\tfrac 15\\\mathsf P(4)&= \tfrac 14\tfrac 15+\tfrac 16\tfrac 15+\tfrac 18\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{12}\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{20}\tfrac 15\\\mathsf P(5)&= 0{\cdot}\tfrac 15+\tfrac 16\tfrac 15+\tfrac 18\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{12}\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{20}\tfrac 15\\\vdots\\\mathsf P(20)&= 0{\cdot}\tfrac 15+0{\cdot}\tfrac 15+0{\cdot}\tfrac 15+0{\cdot}\tfrac 15+\tfrac 1{20}\tfrac 15\end {split}$

A little thought will verify that the sum of these 20 probabilities will equal $1$ as it ought.

That is how, where, and why you include the factor of $\tfrac 15$.